# Email regex string @ symbol not accepted

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I tried to email validate in function, but regex string couldnt allowed. My code is below:

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

[image]

@ symbol give me a warning. this code in script tags.

Comment: share the warning text

Comment: I added warning part @Mhmdrz_A

Comment: This is in a Razor page. Try escaping it using a double @@

Answer (score 0):

For regex, certain characters will act as things you don't want them to.

Say for example, you were starting a capturing group. To do that, you would put parentheses around the text. What if you **didn't** want to open a capturing group, though?

That's where the backslash comes in. Simply use a backslash before the `(` and the group will be gone.

Now, you can also do this with other symbols, too. Stuff like `\` and `/` need to be escaped when searching for them, so you can apply that logic here. You need to use `\@`.

Your new code would be:

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^\S+\@\S+\.\S+$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

console.log(validateEmail("email@example.com"));
console.log(validateEmail("fake email"));
```

Although this code does work, might I suggest using PHP, NodeJS, or other server-side languages to validate emails? Validating in the client will make your website very prone to getting fake emails. This is because you can simply go into Inspect Element and remove that line of code very easily. If I were to copy some code from the source, and then run it, then did some tinkering to make sure the code works, you wouldn't be able to stop me.

Anyhow, I've tested my answer, and I believe it does work.